# Code causing Runtime Error regarding ActiveWorkbook.Save not triggering in my Workbook_Open() event

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling, command

In the code below, I have a log sheet that stores when people open the workbook. When it opens and after it stores the log, i want it to save so that the information isn't lost. This code worked fine for a while, but it's just now throwing a Runtime Error when i run it now, saying

> "Runtime Error 1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Code is below

```
Option Explicit

'creating log sheet entry for when workbook is opened
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim uName As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    uName = Environ("username")

    Sheet9.Unprotect ("Unprotect")

    LastRow = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = uName
    Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = "Opened"
    Sheets("Log Sheet").Cells(LastRow + 1, 3) = Now()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log Sheet").Range("A:A,B:B,C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Sheet9.Protect ("Unprotect")

    Worksheets("Permitting Summary by FY").Activate

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Expected results should be that the entire open event runs without error, and the person who opened it's information is saved to the Log Sheet.

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: This ActiveWorkbook.Save

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim uName As String
    Dim sPassword As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    uName = Environ("username")
    sPassword = "Unprotect"

    With wb.Worksheets("Log Sheet")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Unprotect sPassword
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, "A").Value = uName
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, "B").Value = "Opened"
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, "C").Value = Now()
        .Range("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Protect sPassword
    End With

    wb.Worksheets("Permitting Summary by FY").Activate
    wb.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Runtime error '1004' Applications-defined or object-defined error

Comment: If you are still getting an error on the `wb.Save` line, then it sounds like some sort of permissions issue.  I can confirm that the code is valid.